# Как отключить на определенных сайтах openvpn?

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

использую впн сервер расположенный в европе, в следствие чего нет доступа к некоторым ресурсам в РФ, к примеру авито.

Как отключить впн на некоторых сайтах?

Comment: `VPN` — обобщённое название технологий, позволяющих обеспечить одно или несколько сетевых соединений поверх другой сети. И каким это образом, вы, отключите его? Тем-более отключить его у сайта, к которому у вас нет доступа =)

Comment: Установить маршруты руками =)

Comment: Я находил статьи в которых объясняется, как использовать впн на определенных сайта, по логике вещей предполагаю, что можно сделать и наоборот.

Comment: Вам наверно проще будет скачать `TOR` браузер например или ему аналог.

Comment: К сожалению тор для этого не подходит, в связи с низкой скоростью.

Comment: Если для вас критична скорость, рассмотрите вариант реализации на wireguard. Ибо openvpn - тот еще тормоз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас OpenVPN настроен как основной шлюз, то полагаю, что нужно прописать маршрут к 185.89.12.132 (avito.ru / к примеру) в обход OpenVPN.

```
sudo ip route add 185.89.12.132 via <локальный адрес вашего роутера> dev < название физического сетевого интерфейса >
```

Как вариант, рассмотрите еще iroute в конфиг клиента, который в ccd находится на самом OpenVPN. Что-бы маршрут поднимался при подключении к OpenVPN

Comment: Благодарю, авито заработало частично, а вк полностью)

Comment: Видимо какие-то сервисы авито используют другие ip, потому здесь только путем выцепления ip этих сервисов и добавления маршрутов. А вообще, честно говоря, странно. У меня с немецкой впски (contabo.com) идеально все работает без танцев с бубном.